# Only specific 'columns' from a 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in js:

```
myArray = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];
```

How can I produce an array like this:

```
myAlteredArray = [['2','3'],['5','6'],['8','9']];
```

I basically want to exclude the first *column* out of the array.

Comment: seriously, there are so many resources on the internet regarding javascript arrays manipulating...

Comment: Yes, and I am using one of those resources. I tried a few searches but I couldn't find much. Thank you for helping though :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Quick solution

The easiest way to do this would be to use `map` and `slice`.

```
var subsections = myArray.map(function (subarray) {
    return subarray.slice(1)
})
```

You could also manipulate the subsections in any way you want by doing the following:

```
var subsections = myArray.map(function (subarray) {
    var subsection = subarray.slice(1)
    subsection[1] = parseInt(subsection[1], 10) // parse index 1 in base 10
    return subsection
})
```

## [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

`myArray.map(callback)` executes `callback` on each element in `myArray` and returns a new array made up of all the return values. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function (number) { return 10 - number })
```

would return `[9, 8, 7]` and leave the original array unchanged.

### [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

`myArray.slice(start, [end])` will return a subsection of `myArray` in a new array. If you only pass `start`, `end` is assumed to be the end of the array. For example:

```
['dogs', 'cats', 'fish', 'lizards'].slice(2) == ['fish', 'lizards']
['dogs', 'cats', 'fish', 'lizards'].slice(1, 3) == ['cats', 'fish']
```

*Fun fact: `.slice()` works on [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) too!*

Comment: Okay, this is really cool. And actually quite a bit of useful information for a novice. One question though: is there a way to get `[["2", 3], ["5", 6], ["8", 9]]`? Essentially making one of the columns an `int` instead of a `string`.

Comment: @user1911612 there sure is. I've modified my answer to show this.

Comment: Well, isn't that amazing. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, but note that this will alter original array:

```
myArray = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];

myArray.filter(function(i){

  return i.shift(); 
}); 

console.log(myArray);//logs  [["2", "3"], ["5", "6"], ["8", "9"]]
```

Comment: This works great, but now is there a way to get `[["2", 3], ["5", 6], ["8", 9]]`? Essentially making one of the columns an `int` instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];

var filteredArray = myArray.map(function(currArray,v){
  return currArray.slice(1);
})

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the **array** and use the `slice` function in each **subarray** to extract the first element.

```
  var myArray = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];

  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr[i] = arr.slice(1);
  }
```